# Multiple facebook–like–buttons on one page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-likebox

I would like to add two like-buttons that like different content on the same page. I consider using iframes with the like-buttons contained in them, but it seems as though I need to create a unique facebook app for each thing that is to be liked.

Here are two like-buttons that I intend to put in different iFrames:

http://ballentines.herokuapp.com/1.html
http://ballentines.herokuapp.com/2.html

Comment: So.. What have you tried so far? You can put two like-button on one page without registering/creating an app for each of them.

Comment: NO, I have to have an app, found the error though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had not changed the data-href-attribute in the code.